# javascript: traversing tree breadth first and logging same level values on same line

Tags: javascript

```
function traverseBreadth(root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return;
    }
    var currentNode = root;
    var queue = [];
    queue.push(currentNode)
    while(queue.length > 0) {
        if (queue[0].left != null) {
            queue.push(queue[0].left)
        }
        if (queue[0].right != null) {
            queue.push(queue[0].right)   
        }
        console.log(queue[0])
        queue.shift()
    }    
}
```

I'm trying to make a way so that I can log all same level values on the same line separated by a space.  This current way just logs them in level order, from left to right.
I've tried making a conditional to check if left and right child nodes exist and if so, to log them together however that would throw off what happens when there's only a single left or right node.

Comment: can you give an example of the data and the results you want to determine with the function? Your code seems to be missing a lot, such as something to eventually render your while statement `false`.

Comment: the function just takes a root node from a binary tree  ....the `queue.shift()` removes an index each time through.  The queue will stop getting nodes pushed to once there are no nodes left so `queue.length` will eventually be 0 and the `while` will be false.   An example of running this in console looks like this:

`Node {value: 34, left: Node, right: null}`
`Node {value: 31, left: Node, right: Node}`
`Node {value: 22, left: null, right: null}`
`Node {value: 99, left: null, right: null}`

Answer (score 1):

Below are two functions. The first computes the height of a tree (a test data tree is provided) and then calls a function that I think is what you are looking for.
The function printLevel returns a string with each value at the requested level below root, separated by a space.

```js
// test data

class Node {
  constructor($data = "", $left = null, $right = null) {
    this.data = $data.toString();
    this.left = $left;
    this.right = $right;
  }
}

let tree = new Node(
  "- **a 1** -",
  new Node(
    "- **b 1** -",
    new Node("- **c 1** -"),
    new Node("- **c 2** -")
  ),
  new Node(
    "- **b 2** -",
    new Node("- **c 3** -"),
    new Node("- **c 4** -")
  )
);

// functions

// Breadth First Traverse
// Return a string representing the given tree
function breadthTraverse(tree) {
  let buffer = "";
  if (tree == null) {
    return buffer;
  }
  let temp = tree;
  let height = 0;
  while (temp != null) {
    temp = temp.left;
    ++height;
  }
  for (let i = 1; i <= height; ++i) {
    buffer += printLevel(tree, i) + "<br />";
  }
  return buffer;
}


function printLevel(root, level) {
  let buffer = "";
  if (root == null) {
    return buffer;
  }
  if (level == 1) {
    buffer += root.data;
  } else if (level > 1) {
    buffer += printLevel(root.left, level - 1);
    buffer += " ";
    buffer += printLevel(root.right, level - 1);
  }
  return buffer;
}

// test functions
let output = `
 <div>
  <h4>Breadth First Traverse:</h4>
  <br />
  ${breadthTraverse(tree)}
  <br />
 </div>
`;

// display logistics
let con = document.getElementById("session");
con.innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<div id="session">
</div>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value.

Comment: added an explanation. hopefully that clears up any confusion